# Magento doesn't show CVV for customers when checking out -2

Tags: onepage-checkout, paypal-pro

Sorry (I'm repeating this question because I can't edit or comment on my previous question)..

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.2 with latest updates installed and a custom Theme that I paid for. If a customer checks out and gets to the payment section, he/she enters credit card information and will be able to see everything on the screen EXCEPT the CVV. If you try to add anything in that box, nothing shows up and it seems like that field is not allowing numbers to show up.

I've tested an actual transaction on (Live) and I was able to complete the transaction. The issue is if you don't click and add any numbers in the CVV, you will get the error message that you're missing the CVV. but you can click on it and type the "invisible numbers" and it will complete the transaction.

How can this be fixed? I would like to allow numbers to show for the customer or remove the CVV completely.

I would like to know how to find the page where I can edit the field and make it show the numbers instead of hiding the numbers or not showing any characters in the field.

PS: I'm using Paypal pro

Comment: That's hard to know what's causing this. Does it work if you turn off the custom theme and use the rwd theme? If so, then it's with your theme. I would inspect the element in your browser and see if there is css that is changing the field.

Comment: As a newbie, I'm not sure how to turn the theme off and return the rwd theme back on. I'm also working on production. I want to be careful with my options. If anyone knows where to find the page that defines the form and the CVV field properties, that would be helpful. I can look at it and share it with everyone to know what's stopping the numbers from showing.

Comment: Go to Admin > System > Design and check the theme, as well as System > Configuration > General > Design.

Comment: @PhilipDeatherage that path doesn't show where to find the exact path of what file has the CVV form properties. I'm trying to locate the file that has that property of not showing the characters. Thanks!

Comment: No, that was in reply to you saying you didn't know where to turn off the theme. See my answer below for turning off the CVV and/or identifying the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn off CVV for PayPal pro, go to Admin > System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods > PayPal All-in-One Payment Solutions, and then click the "Configure" next to PayPal Payments Pro. Click the "Advanced Settings," and change "Require CVV Entry" to "No."

To identify the file that this is in, turn on template hints. To do this, go to Admin > System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer, and choose the Debug Tab. Now, switch the configuration scope to the store of the site you are viewing. Once you do that, in the Debug tab you will see an option "Template Path Hints." Change that to Yes. Now, when you load the front-end, you will see lots of red lines and paths to files.

You can also use the inspect feature of your browser to see the related css, etc. The css would be the first thing I would check, since it's seems to be there, but just hidden.

Comment: thanks for the tip! By using the Developer Tools in Chrome Browser (on Windows by pressing  ctrl + shift + C), I was able to look find the CSS options. After playing around with it, I had to override the existing CSS that was (3em !important) to (!important).. When got rid of (3em) I'm able to see the CVV numbers but now it takes more than 3 characters which I'm fine with as a workaround.